# Correct way to assemble If statement in array

Tags: php, if-statement

So i have an array which is working fine, however in the following code I would like to add a statement checking for $result['price'] =! NULL before dividing. 
I have a few items in my array which has a value of 0.00 so I'd like not to divide by zero :)

```
'stock_status'=> $result['stock_status'],
'saving'      => round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0),
'tax'         => $tax,
```

I've tried some combinations of the following:

```
'stock_status'=> $result['stock_status'],
'saving'      => if (!($result['price'] == NULL)) {  
round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0),
    }
'tax'         => $tax,
```

But no success, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just FYI: Divide by zero in PHP gives a warning only, it won't bring your script to halt.

Comment: @hakre perhaps you are right, but my css went awol in ie9 :)
Thanks for all your answers, I didnt get to test every piece of code since the first I tried worked fine. 
I've learned quite a bit from this somewhat trivial post, amazing how many solutions there can be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside the array I use,

```
$saving = (! isset($result['price']))?round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0):$result['price'];
```

Then just write

```
'saving'      => $saving,
```

Comment: +1: Next to having a clear name for the variable, this also has the benefit to better format that single-line over multiple lines when done really well.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a ternary operator:

```
[bool] ? if_true : if_false

'saving' => is_null($result['price']) ? 0 : round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0);
```

Comment: what if `$result['price']` value is 0 ?

Comment: You'll get a division-by-0 error. You can tweak the boolean condition to suit your needs.

Comment: but your code only check `is_null($result['price'])`. so, I think if these value is 0 then execute the other.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `is_null(0)` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

NULL means something like nonexistent, empty

You want to check for 0:

```
'saving'      => if (!($result['price'] > 0)) {
```

Besides that, when setting it up, it is always a good idea to first create the working script with basic steps:

```
$value = 0;
if (!($result['price'] > 0)) 
  {
  $value = round( 100*( ($result['price'] - $result['special']) /$result['price'] + 0.01) , 0)
  }
```

after which you can enter $value into the array. You can then always start merging things using ternary operators. But I have never understood the need for that (But I don't have heavy server loads to worry about)

Comment: You sure? Most programming laguages there is a big differene

Answer (score 0):

```
'stock_status'=> $result['stock_status'],
'saving'      => if (!$result['price'] == NULL || !$result['price'] == 0) {  
    round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0),
}
'tax'         => $tax,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your error might be here:

```
'saving' => if (!($result['price'] == NULL)) {  
    round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0),
}
```

the comma is not where it should be, after the `}`
The correct snippet:

```
'saving' => if (!($result['price'] == NULL)) {  
    round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0)
},
```

Comment: this won't help to solve the problem. Your code only check whether the `$result['price']` value is NULL. Not check the zero value

Comment: It helps to solve the syntax error what I thought was the problem he had.

Answer (score 0):

```
'stock_status'=> $result['stock_status'],
'saving'      => $result['price']? round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'] + 0.01)*100, 0):0,
'tax'         => $tax,
```

Will work, if price is NULL or Zero value